# How to retrieve column values in the following format using SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a database with the following kind of values in two columns:

```
OPERATIONCONTEXT        MANAGEDOBJECT
.oc.IN_HSI_service  NNMi_NODE .nodei_v1_tns.OMi-DP NODEPrepaid_HSI_Service_MUMBAI
```

I have the requirement to write a SQL query to retieve these columns values separeted by a comma (,) in such a way that the `OPERATIONCONTEXT` column value is retrieved as it is but the  `MANAGEDOBJECT` value is retrieved in a way that i get just the first two words separeted by a space.

Ex: I need to write a SQL query to retrieve the following result from the above sample DB data:

```
.oc.IN_HSI_service,NNMi_NODE .nodei_v1_tns.OMi-DP
```

I am able to get the two full column values separeted by a comma (,) with the following query:

```
SELECT distinct OPERATIONCONTEXT ||','|| MANAGEDOBJECT from $ALB_BASE_TABLE where OPERATIONCONTEXT is not NULL;
```

But, ofcourse along with the result i would like to put a restriction to check for `not NULL` and `distinct` values instead of repeated results and want to put the result in a CSV file through shell script. Any idea how to write the query?

PS: This is Oracle Database.

Comment: Yes Shree, it is Oracle 11g

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
substr(MANGEDOBJECT, 0, INSTR(MANAGEDOBJECT, ' ', 1, 2))
```

Of course, it would be good to check if they are two spaces in string.

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/27805), and OracleDoc for [Instr](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm#OLADM564)